# reinstalled multibit wallet

Tags: wallet, multibit, lost-bitcoins, lost-wallet, wallet-recovery

I had to remove a copy of multibit wallet from my system & after multiple times of trying to get it to work on my 64 bit system I can now open multibit wallet. I guess when I removed the program that the wallet .dat files were removed as well but I do have the wallet addresses that were removed. Is it possible to retrieve the missing data? Can I just send my bitcoin to another wallet or do I have to have the .dat file in order to accomplish this? Hopefully I have not caused all my bitcoin to go away permanantly. Any advice on this subject will be totally appreciated big time.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MultiBit's Getting Started](https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_gettingStarted.html), the wallet file of MultiBit seems to be named **`multibit.wallet`**, not wallet.dat. You might want to try searching for that instead.

Sorry to break the bad news, but the **addresses aren't sufficient** to regain control of the bitcoins. If that were the case, anyone that knew your address could grab your coins, and addresses are public information which would make for a very insecure system.

Therefore, you need your **private keys** in order to transfer your bitcoins.